How can I shift the content vertically down in PDFsharp?
I am creating a PDF document using PDFsharp library. I am able to create header and footer on multiple pages, however my header and footer is overlapping with my main content.
Here is the basic code structure :
public static MemoryStream DrawHeaderFooter(MemoryStream ms){
            using (PdfDocument document = PdfReader.Open(ms, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Modify))
            {
             for(int pageNum=0;pageNum<=document.Pages.Count;pageNum++)
             {
              //header footer logic
             }
              ms.Position=40;
              document.Save(ms,false);
            }
            return ms;
}

I want to shift the MemoryStream position vertically on my page by 40 units, but ms.Position=40 is not working. My main content is in form of a table and I want to reduce length of the table too by the offset that is by 40 units.
Is it possible to achieve the same in PDFsharp? If yes then can anyone explain how is it possible?

You can create a new PDF, create a new page in that PDF, draw the existing PDF page anywhere on the new page, eventually changing its size while drawing it.
Do this for any pages in the PDF.
Then save the new PDF under any name you want or save it in a MemoryStream.
This sample demonstrates the functions you need:
https://pdfsharp.net/wiki/TwoPagesOnOne-sample.ashx
